# How To refresh GridView using search Button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a gridview and a search textbox in my aspx page. Now my requirement is that as soon as I type anything in this textbox the gridview must be refreshed according to typed value of textbox.

Is it possible using Gridview or I need to go for Jquery grid?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you can use Jquery go for it

Comment: you must put an onkeyup/onkeydown attribute in the input field. In the onkeyup/onkeydown you need to fire a function (ajax) that will request the updated grid from asp. I'm doing something similar but in php. the function in the onkeyup can be jquery for making it more easy

Comment: btw, if your grid has already a search function. probably you have to click a search button... you can try moving the function in the onclick attribute from the search button to the onkeyup from the input field. if the grid is already using ajax this probably will work to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javascript to detect the typing in the textbox. It is best to set a timeout when the user presses a key to avoid doing many postbacks:

```
var timer;
function chk_me(){

   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer=setTimeout(function refreshGridview(){...},1000);
}
```

Use the [GetPostBackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.getpostbackeventreference%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method to get javascript which causes a postback on the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

I have pulled thout out of a project of mine from a while ago, this was what my 2 text boxes TextChanged event fired

I would run the procedure again (with pattern matching) and then attach this to the binding source.

If you only want this to happen on pressing the button then put it on the button press event

```
 private void FindTextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] param = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[3];
                param[0] = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@param1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                param[1] = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                param[2] = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@SysproDB", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                param[0].Value = txt1.Text;
                param[1].Value = txt2.Text;
                param[2].Value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SysproDB"].ToString();
                param[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                param[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                param[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                result = (DataTable)SessionClass.dbc.runStoredProc(procedure, param);
                BindingSource.DataSource = result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the gridview you will need to do a postback when something is typed:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myTextBox" onkeyup="this.form.submit();" />
```

Adding **onkeyup="this.form.submit();"** to your textbox will make it submit the form to the server after a key is released.

If the databinding of your gridview is done on pageload then this is all you will need to add.

If your databinding is triggered by some other action, like a search button you must trigger it from javascript or use WebMethod to call the databinding.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />

        <!-- put your grid inside the update panel too -->

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: This will only do a postback when the TextBox loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply dataBind the datasource that the grid view is bound to.

```
Datasource1.selectparameters["someParameters"].defaultvalue=Textbox1.text;
Datasource1.DataBind();
Gridview1.DataSource=Datasource1;
Gridview1.DataBind();
```